# PHP/PDO and SQL Server connection and i18n issues

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In our web-app we use PHP5.2.6 + PDO to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database and store Russian texts.

Database collation is `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`, table collation is `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`, column type is `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

We tried connecting to a database using two following schemes, both causing different problems.

1. *PDO mssql:*

   ```
   $dbh = new PDO ('mssql:host='.$mssql_server.';dbname='.$mssql_db, $mssql_login, $mssql_pwd);
   ```

   in which case a result of a simple query like that:

   ```
   SELECT field1 FROM tbl1 WHERE id=1
   ```

   shows `field1` data truncated to 255 bytes.
2. *PDO odbc:*

   ```
   $dbh = new PDO ('odbc:DSN=myDSN;UID='.$mssql_login.';PWD='.$mssql_pwd);
   ```

   in which case a result of the same query shows full not truncated data but with question marks instead of Russian symbols.

---

Notes:

- In the SQL Management Studio data is not truncated and Russian symbols are displayed properly as well.
- We have Windows 2003 Enterprise Edition SP2

So what should we choose as a connection method and how to fix corresponding issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing `SET NAMES "charset"` after you connect.

I don't know what the charset to match `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS` is, but try "Cyrillic"?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this to get usable data from my NVARCHAR fields in MSSQL:

```
$_ = iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $_);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always had the best luck using utf8_general_ci across the board - for connections, collations - everything.

However, I only have that experience with MySQL and PostgreSql - not with SQL Server.

As to your DSN question - I'm not sure.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is definetely in PHP/PDO - because when we connect to the same database in .NET, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not set on PDO, use [FreeTDS](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) - aka procedural mssql_* calls. This is one of the recommended work arounds until PDO is *fixed*. Since PHP 5.1.2, FreeTDS has a [mssql.charset-option](http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.configuration.php).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem too, with an implementation of SQL server 2005 and PHP 5.x using PDO.  When I changed nvarchar(MAX) field to nvarchar(255) the odd question mark characters stopped appearing.  I definitely believe it has to do with the ODBC drivers in PDO and MS SQL server.  When you implicitly specify the max characters in your varchar, it solves the problem.