# PDO Connection string for SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, pdo

What should my PDO constructor/DSN/connection string look like to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database?

```
$dbh = new PDO('??');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) site. It always helps me, or this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178530/php-pdo-and-sql-server-connection-and-i18n-issues).